# Attempting to implement share action intent on webpage

Tags: material-design-lite

As stated in title. MDL cards/templates etc come with fancy looking share buttons. How exactly do we make them work how we see they do on phones apps? I want a user to be able to press the share button and have the list of apps to share via to show up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with current web technology. The only API that was in progress to allow it was [Web Intents](http://webintents.org/) but this has since [been abandoned](https://paul.kinlan.me/what-happened-to-web-intents/).

The share button could open up a dialog or something that has a Reddit share, Digg button, Facebook share, Google Plus shares, etc within them. That way they are only initialized when called. But you need to specifically program what you want to share out to.